# Can someone please clarify the Birthday Effect for me?

Tags: hash, birthday-paradox

Please help interpret the Birthday effect as described in Wikipedia:

> A birthday attack works as follows:
>
> 1. Pick any message m and compute h(m).
> 2. Update list L. Check if h(m) is in the list L.
> 3. if (h(m),m) is already in L, a colliding message pair has been found.
>      else save the pair (h(m),m) in the
>      list L and go back to step 1.
>
> From the birthday paradox we know that we can expect to find a
>   matching entry, after performing about
>   2^(n/2) hash evaluations.

Does the above mean 2^(n/2) iterations through the above entire loop (i.e. 2^(n/2) returns to step 1), OR does it mean 2^(n/2) comparisons to individual items already in L?

Comment: Hash evaluations. as in "compute h(m)" in step 1

Comment: oh right, hash evaluation would mean computing a hash for a message, thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the wikipedia link you are quoting? I don't see this text there.

Comment: http://ehash.iaik.tugraz.at/wiki/Generic_Attacks 
Evidently it wasn't wikipedia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means 2^(n/2) iterations through the loop. But note that `L` would not be a normal list here, but a hash table mapping `h(m)` to `m`. So each iteration would only need a constant number (O(1)) of comparisons in average, and there would be O(2^(n/2)) comparisons in total.

If L had been a normal array or a linked list, then the number of comparisons would be much larger since you would need to search through the whole list each iteration. This would be a bad way to implement this algorithm though.

Comment: just one other thing regarding stack overflow - am I supposed to be updating the status somehow of members here that answer my questions.  If so, how is that done.

Comment: @Mark: If you like an answer you can upvote it (click the up arrow to the left of the answer). If an answer solves your problem, you can accept it - click the tick mark to the left of the answer.

Comment: Well it looks like I'll have to register to do that.

Comment: If items are not added the list L, or rather periodically deleted from L after L reaches some set maximum (but before a collision is found), any idea on what effect that would have on the 2^(n/2) birthday bound.

Comment: @Mark: If you limit the size of L to k where k<2^(n/2), then you would need about (2^n)/k iterations to find a collision.

Comment: I really appreciate that.  Sorry for not updating your status yet, but when I tried to register just now and, at other times in the past, it gives me some confusing directives about having to join Yahoo or something, so I always bail out.

Comment: Maybe you can number crunch this: There are m groups of messages, each group with a maximum of k members. a collision is only relevant if it involves the members of the same group. How many hash evaluations to get such a collision. [So m signifies the number of subgroups of messages - not a particular message]

Comment: I mean the collision has to involve members of the same group.

Comment: @Mark: If k is much smaller than 2^(n/2) then the birthday paradox won't come into play, and there will be a very small chance that a group will have a collision. So you'll need a lot of hash evaluations: if I'm not mistaken, about 2^(n+1).