# Generate list of unique random numbers in constant time

Tags: java, algorithm, random

I need 100 random numbers from the range 1 to 1,000,000. The numbers must be unique, no duplicates.
It's similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196017/unique-random-numbers-in-o1), but my range is too large to create an array from.

I need to generate these 100 random numbers many, many times, so generation needs to be as fast as possible, preferably O(1). What's the fastest way to do it?

Comment: Generating N numbers will never be less that O(N).

Comment: But OP wants to generate `100`, not arbitrary number of random numbers.

Comment: @MiserableVariable If you put it that way, it is **always** going to be O(1), no matter what you do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a HashSet and a [Mersenne Twister](http://www.cs.gmu.edu/~sean/research/mersenne/MersenneTwisterFast.java).

code:

```
    MersenneTwisterFast ran = new MersenneTwisterFast();
    long time = System.nanoTime();
    Set set = new HashSet(100);
    while( set.size()<100) {
        set.add(ran.nextInt(1000000));
   }

System.out.println(System.nanoTime()-time+" : nano");
System.out.println(set.size());
```

The output was:

320000 : nano

100

Fast enough? and yes, this is O(1) as you always do 100 numbers.

Beware of the [Birthday paradox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766910/can-someone-please-clarify-the-birthday-effect-for-me), here you select 100 out of 1000000, thats ok but if you boost the 100 up, it will take longer and longer.

Comment: Cool. Didn't know about the twister.

Comment: The doc says it's only a third faster. In fact, `Random` is only a third slower than `MersenneTwisterFast`, which is even less difference.

Comment: Javadocs I found for it say nextInt() "Returns an integer drawn uniformly from 0 to n-1".  Does that mean it's guaranteed to never return a duplicate until you've called nextInt n times?

Comment: I confirmed it using Caliper, really is over twice as fast as Random (Lion, JSE 7).

Comment: Hm... I now extended my test and the story suddenly changed. The raw generator (`nextInt()`) is indeed twice as fast, but as soon as you use a bound (`nextInt(100)`) the difference melts to zero.

Comment: @Frank: What happens if there are high collisions? It seems that `ran.nextInt()` may be called `150` times or even more. Is there any limit?

Comment: Please look at the Birthday Paradox, the link is in my answer...but for this solution it means it will get slow.

Comment: @YogendraSingh do you have that with this code? i did put in a small if to detect collisions but with only 100 numbers i did get 0 after 100 test runs.

Comment: @Frank: I was more thinking theoretically than trying it. Since we are generating 100 numbers only, its low, but if we generate 100000 numbers, collision may be very high. Also if I do the same using random.nextInt(1000000), it should be same percentile of collisions. I thought of suggesting the same `Set` based approach using random.nextInt(n)), but I got hesitant just be thinking of the collisions. I haven't gauged the time difference though.

Comment: @YogendraSingh that is what the Birthday paradox is all about.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18996/discussion-between-frank-and-yogendra-singh)

Comment: Working perfectly, really fast too. I'd never heard of MT before. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Divide your range in 100 parts and generate a random number from each sub-range.
I think it'll work fine in your case.

Alternatively, generate random numbers and put them in a HashSet. when the size of the HashSet is 100, you break.

Though If you want to generate 100 random numbers, it'll always be O(1).

Comment: This equally spaces the numbers. Therefore they are not random!

Answer (score 0):

Create  a Random here.

```
 Random generator = new Random();
```

And create a timer class  to execute the function every x seconds

```
 int d = 1000; //milliseconds 
 ActionListener t = new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      //...Number genration task Here

  for (int idx = 1; idx <= 10; ++idx){
  int r = generator.nextInt(1000000);
  log("Generated : " + r);
  }
  }
  };
  new Timer(a,t).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: this solution only works quickly when the amount of possible generated numbers greatly exceeds the amount of numbers you have to generate!

Edit: you can use this exact code with a Mersenne Twister also if you like

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Random;

public class MakeRand {
    private static final HashSet<Integer> theNumbers = new HashSet<Integer>();
    private static final Random myRandom = new Random();

    private static void addNumber() {
         int newNumber = -1;
         do {
            newNumber = myRandom.nextInt(1000000) + 1;
         } while(theNumbers.contains(newNumber));

         theNumbers.add(newNumber);
    }

    public static void populate(int howMany) {
        for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++) {
            addNumber();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        populate(100);

        Iterator<Integer> iter = theNumbers.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()) {
            Integer current = iter.next();
            System.out.println(current);
        }
    }
}
```